# Approximating $\sin(\frac{x}{2})$ by trigonometric polynomials in the uniform norm

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, approximation

Find a trygonometric polynomial of the form $$a_0+a_{1} \sin (x)+ a_2 \cos (x)$$ that best approximates the function $$\sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ in the uniform norm on the interval $[-\pi,\pi]$. I can't think of a way to approach this problem. Should I be looking for alternating points or is there a way to transform this into polynomial approximation?
I would appreciate a hint.

Comment: It's not an easy optimization problem, to be sure, but have you tried setting the gradient (with respect to $ a_1, a_2, a_3 $ ) equal to zero.  My intuition is that it can be computed with the implicit function theorem.  By the way, is a very close approximation desired, or an exact answer?  Because if you wanted a very close approximation, I might first approximate in $L^2$ norm (which is much, much easier) and then gradient descent.

Comment: Thanks, I think my teacher might have mistaken the norms by accident, but I thought maybe I was blind for some trick. This excersice for sure wasn't supposed to be approached numerically ( with gradient descent etc.).

Comment: I see.  Yes, if you want to approximate in $ L^2 $ norm, you have only to look up the formula for projecting a vector (in this case the vector is the function $ f = \sin(x/2) $) onto a subspace (in this case, the three-dimensional subspace spanned by $ 1, \sin(x), \cos(x) $).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At $x=\pm \pi$ you get the residuals $f(\pi)-p(\pi)=1-a_0+a_2$ and $f(-\pi)-p(-\pi)=-1-a_0+a_2$. The sum of these errors is
$$
|f(\pi)-p(\pi)|+|f(-\pi)-p(-\pi)|=|1+(a_2-a_0)|+|-1+(a_2-a_0)|=2\max(1,|a_2-a_0|).
$$
The best result you can get in the sense of a uniform error is when both errors are $1$.

However, the uniform distance of the given function to the zero function $p(x)=0$ is $1$, so that this trivial approximation already realizes the best uniform approximation.